# ¿Cómo sumar con condición y ofrecer el resultado en un nuevo df?

Tags: python

Os pongo en situación. Pongamos que tengo 1 df que contiene 2 columnas:

```
COL 1: nombres de personas ["NOMBRE"]
COL 2: gastos de cada persona ["GASTO"]
```

Lo que sucedes es que aparecen varios gastos de cada persona. 
Me gustaría poder sumar los gastos de cada persona y poder visualizar el gasto total de cada persona en un nuevo df para poder visualizar luego el top10, top20, etc con un simple .head().

He intentado agrupar las personas en la columna "NOMBRE" usando groupby, pero me devuelve un error y tampoco puedo he podido aplicar la función .sum.

Creo que lo que intento hacer es muy fácil, pero no hay forma. No lo consigo.

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Buenas ¿puedes mostrar lo que has hecho y  a partir de allí intentamos resolverlo?

Comment: Pon el código ese en el que intentaste `groupby()` y el mensaje de error que te ha dado, a ver si vemos qué estaba mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la columna **GASTO** es numerica

```
nuevo_df = df.groupby(by=['NOMBRE']).agg({'GASTO': 'sum'})
nuevo_df.head()
```

para convertirla que sea numerica

```
df.GASTO = pd.to_numeric(df.GASTO, errors='coerce')
```